# String concatenation in Tikz

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

How can I replace the sequence (in a `pgfplots`, Tikz environment)

```
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy1.txt};
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy2.txt};
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy3.txt};
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy4.txt};
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy5.txt};
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy6.txt};
\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy7.txt};
```

by a more compact `\foreach` construct?

Comment: `\foreach \i in {1,...,7} {\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy\i.txt};}`

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work. @percusse: Could you explain, why the use of \pgfplotsinvokeforeach is preferable (apart of operating at a lower level).

Comment: If you use `\i` in a context where it is needed to be expanded it will not work. The latter makes sure that the value is inserted as is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the expanded for loop of `pgfplots`

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,7}{\addplot[black] table {plot3/fnxspy#1.txt};}
```

Comment: Was looking for this for long though in a different context. Thanks!